# Git commit not showing up in log even though the commit was made

Tags: git

I was working on a remote machine and I made changes to a few files, added them and committed the changes. I also always use git log to see that the commit is there (just out of practice).

After this I did a post-review to get my code reviewed. I add this statement because, I'm able to see the commit and the changes on the code-review UI and have pushed my changes via the UI.

But when I run git log on the remote machine, I do not see the commit (and git status shows the already committed changes as yet to be added). I would be forced to think that I never made the commit at all if not for the fact that I can actually see it on the review board UI.

Please excuse me if I'm missing something obvious here. I'm trying to understand why this has happened? And, if there's a way for me to see that commit again (without pulling those changes, which I myself pushed).

Further details: 
There's only one local branch. 
I've tried git reflog, as some threads seemed to suggest trying this. 
I know the commit hash - can I use this in some way?

**EDIT: This question is no longer relevant. The issue is not anything to do with the above details and instead, had to do with the way one of our internal tools functions. Thank you for the help!**

Comment: did you do a git pull on the remote machine?

Comment: You mention "working on a remote machine" (as in, a server somewhere, probably, but one with a Git repository on it). Who *else* has access to this server, either by direct ssh login, or by pushing to that Git repository, or similar? It seems clear enough that someone made a change to that repository, and the "someone" was probably not you; and if it is a server, it probably has many "someone"s who can do things on it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. Turns out this has nothing to do with the commands I used or anything specified in the question. Instead, it had to do with the way one of our internal tools is configured.